# Integrating D3 with angular2 final release using angular-cli beta 15

Tags: d3.js, angular, angular-cli

I have tried many attempts but I am fail to successfully using D3 with property intellisense working in Angular2 Final release using angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15.

Any successful attempts or hint or steps would be helpful.

I have tried using d3-ng2-service as well.

Either ends up in lots of compilation error with missing type def.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in a CLI project a week ago

```
npm install d3 --save
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev

//and in your code:
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

(repeat as necessary for other d3 modules i.e. `d3-color`)

you can see the project I was playing with [here](https://github.com/Brocco/ip-graph)